# Styles on divs not stretching when in container div with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to create a container div with a series of styled divs inside it. I want the container to be a fixed width and show a scroll bar if any of the contained divs are wider than the container. I can do this by setting the container to auto overflow-x and nowrap whitespace but I can't seem to figure out how to get styles on the contained elements to stretch.

Here's an example of what I'm doing

```html
    <div style="width:200px;overflow-x:auto;white-space:nowrap">
      <div style="background:#dddddd">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
      <div style="background:#aaaaaa">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
      <div style="background:#bbbbbb;">AAAAAAAAAAAAA   </div>
    </div>
```

And here's what I get

[image: Example]

As you can see the scroll bar appears but the styles of the individual divs doesn't stretch. So when you scroll right to show the rest of the content the background stops.

I've tried playing around with widths and margins but can't seem to get the styles to stretch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add ;display=table to the style for the internal div's, then they will each be just wide enough to accommodate the text data inside them.

Edited in response to first comment:

You can make them all as wide as the longest div like this.

```
<div style="width:200px;overflow-x:auto;white-space:nowrap">
    <div style="display:table">
        <div style="background:#dddddd;display:table-row">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div style="background:#aaaaaa;display:table-row">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div style="background:#bbbbbb;display:table-row;">AAAAAAAAAAAAA   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like it if they were all as wide as the longest div.

Comment: Yeah the table-rows did it. I had to add table-cell divs inside of those to allow for padding/height but I got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need add some `width` to divs inside div with scroll: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/q2Ld3g71/1/)

```
<div style="width:200px;overflow-x:scroll;white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="width: 2000px;background:#dddddd">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div style="width: 1000px; background:#aaaaaa">AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div style="background:#bbbbbb;">AAAAAAAAAAAAA   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does what I want but doesn't scale. The divs will be as wide as they are set regardless of the content.